# Excel VBA - Can I manipulate data on another workbook?

Tags: vba, excel

## Background:

Every month I need to run a report. However, before I can do this, I must export some data in to excel. Once the data is in excel, I have to alter some columns and get the format correct before it is appended to the end of another document to do some analysis on.

## What I would like:

I would like to have the document that I append the data to open. I will then export the data in to excel from my program (excel just opens with the data and it is not saved anywhere) and from my larger document, run a VBA script that will alter the data on the other workbook (Book1) so that it can be copied over to the analysis document when in the correct format.

## What I have so far:

I have started basic. So far all I am trying to do is set all the cells to the correct height to make it easier to read. However, when I run this code, I get:

> Run-time error '9':
>
> > Subscript out of range

The code I have so far is:

```
Sub Data_Ready_For_Transfer()

' Format all cell heights to 15
    With Workbooks("Book1.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Cells.RowHeight = 15
    End With
End Sub
```

It appears to be having issues with the `With Workbooks("Book1.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1")` part of the code. I have also tried `With Workbooks("Book1").Worksheets("Sheet1")`  and I have tried this with the open, unsaved document and a saved version of the workbook.

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: 1) workbook `Book1` should be opened. check please again `With Workbooks("Book1").Worksheets("Sheet1")` - it should work if you really have workbook `Book1` _opened_ with sheet `Sheet1`. 2) You should use `.Cells.RowHeight = 15` instread `Cells.RowHeight = 15` to specify that cells belongs to book1->sheet1

Comment: Workbook `Book1` is open but I still get the issue. - Thanks for the other amendment suggestion.

Comment: Let us do a little test, run this code: `For Each wb In Workbooks: MsgBox wb.Name: Next`. Have it pop up you a message with `Book1`?

Comment: Well that's interesting. Despite having both workbooks open, it only sees one. Does it matter that the Book1 is not a window in the same instance of excel. Rather a new excel application open?

Comment: I've just thought about that:) when you are using `For Each wb In Workbooks` it actually the same as `For Each wb In Application.Workbooks` for current `Application`. If you have another appication object, say `xlApp`, you should access workbooks using this application: `For Each wb In xlApp.Workbooks`

Comment: and also try `Set wb = GetObject("Book1")` to get opened workbook instance (from another application). And then use `With wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")`

Comment: That makes sense, well explained. However, I have changed `In Workbooks` to `In xlApp.Workbooks` and now I get a Run-time error 424 - Object Required?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49458/discussion-between-simoco-and-petay87)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As follow up from comments, workbook `Book1` was opened in *another* instance of `Application` object.

In that case this code should work (for already opened workbook):

```
Sub Data_Ready_For_Transfer()
    Dim wb As Workbook

    Set wb = GetObject("Book1")

    'if we get workbook instance then
    If Not wb Is Nothing Then
        With wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
            .Cells.RowHeight = 15
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

One more issue, I've changed `Cells.RowHeight = 15` to `.Cells.RowHeight = 15` to specify, that `Cells` belongs to workbook `Book1` sheet `Sheet1`.